# mvn tomcat7:run - How does it work?

Tags: tomcat, maven, tomcat7, maven-tomcat-plugin

I just want to understand, because I got the code from another question, and it's working fine, but I don't understand the flow of this operation.

This is my understanding of Apache Maven Tomcat plugin for Tomcat 7, when using mvn tomcat7:run with following configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <configuration>
        <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

It creates a new Tomcat 7 instance with default configuration, then use project war file as a deployed project in this instance, am I right, please correct me if I am wrong, or someone please describe to me how this process is working, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`pom.xml` of the `tomcat7-maven-plugin` depends on Tomcat's bundles. Maven download them and the plugin starts an embedded Tomcat instance with the webproject.

`mvn -X tomcat7:run` prints the configuration. Some interesting parts:

```
[INFO] Preparing tomcat7:run
[DEBUG] (s) resources = [Resource {targetPath: null, filtering: false, 
    FileSet {directory: /workspace/webtest1/src/main/resources, 
    PatternSet [includes: {}, excludes: {}]}}]
...
[DEBUG] (f) additionalConfigFilesDir = /workspace/webtest1/src/main/tomcatconf
[DEBUG] (f) configurationDir = /workspace/webtest1/target/tomcat
...
[DEBUG] (f) path = /webtest1
...
[DEBUG] (f) port = 8080
[DEBUG] (f) project = ...:webtest1:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ /workspace/webtest1/pom.xml
...
[DEBUG] (f) warSourceDirectory = /workspace/webtest1/src/main/webapp
...
[INFO] Creating Tomcat server configuration at /workspace/webtest1/target/tomcat
...
[DEBUG] adding classPathElementFile file:/workspace/webtest1/target/classes/
[DEBUG] add dependency to webapploader org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.5.6:compile
...
```

`warSourceDirectory` points to `src` (not `target`), so it runs as an usual dynamic web project, you could change your JSPs, HTMLs and it will visible immediately. Because of that the `target/tomcat/webapps` folder is empty.

The site of v1.2 contains a more detailed documentation than the site of 2.0-SNAPSHOT about configuration: http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html.

Comment: I tried to change the HTML and CSS static content in the default warSourceDirectory, but the changes are not reflecting without restarting the server. what should i do to avoid server restart for static content changes?

Comment: @prabu , just refresh the server url in browser