# mvn tomcat:run does not pick up css files

Tags: css, spring, tomcat, maven-2

I have asked another question related to this in this thread [Where to put css resources in a maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836930/where-do-css-and-javascript-files-go-in-a-maven-web-app-project)

thinking that I was not putting the css resources under the right location in a Maven project structure. Right now I have a folder under webapp called **css** and I have the css resources there. My problem is that when I do `mvn clean tomcat:run` those css resources do not seem to be picked up and put appropriately in the target folder so my application cannot pick them up.

Does anybody know why?

**UPDATE**

My goal is to avoid building the war upon deployment for rapid development.I have changed my Maven command to: `mvn clean war:exploded tomcat:run`

The application runs fine but the css is not being picked up. If I go to the browser and type: `http://localhost:8080/appname/css/styles.css`

I get a Spring Framework error saying `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/appname/css/styles.css` in DispatcherServlet

In other Spring Java apps that I have built using traditional project style (not maven) I was able to access the css from the borwser with the url above. I have made sure that the css folder is hanging straight out of the webapp folder.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE: Adding web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
                 classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml                  
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I do not have the Dispatcher servlet mapped to /* and it still tries to access CSS files through the DispatcherServlet.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question so I'm not posting it as one, but you may want to consider hosting your static files _outside_ Tomcat, with a web server like Apache or nginx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tomcat:run` use the `src` folder, not the `target`. Your `css` files are in a good place in `src/main/webapp/css`. They should be available from a browser.

`mvn -X tomcat:run` prints the configuration. Some interesting parts:

```
[INFO] Preparing tomcat:run
[DEBUG] (s) resources = [Resource {targetPath: null, filtering: false, 
    FileSet {directory: /workspace/webtest1/src/main/resources, 
    PatternSet [includes: {}, excludes: {}]}}]
...
[DEBUG] (f) warSourceDirectory = /workspace/webtest1/src/main/webapp
```

You can find some more details in this answer: [mvn tomcat7:run - How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823346/mvn-tomcat7run-how-does-it-work/7828084#7828084)

For the second question/update: I think you mapped a Spring servlet to `/*` and it does not handle static content. Post your `web.xml` and Spring configuration. Maybe you just need a [`mvc:resources`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources) into your Spring configuration. This also could be useful: [How to handle static content in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483063/spring-mvc-3-and-handling-static-content-am-i-missing-something)

Comment: Updated quetion with web.xml. So do you have to use **<mvc:resources>** when you put your css under the right location **src/main/webapp/css** ?

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify this is what I had to do:

1. Make sure that in your **servlet-context.xml** you have as follows:

   ```
   <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
   ```
2. Create a folder if does not already exist under webapps called **resources**
3. Place your **css** folder along with css files there
4. Reference my css file as follows:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/css/960.css"/>
   ```