# Run Maven Tomcat 7 as exploded

Tags: tomcat, maven, tomcat7, maven-plugin

How to run Maven tomcat7 as exploded? I 'm trying to run web application which read dynamic files form same context folder.

I have tried to use this :

```
mvn tomcat7:run
```

And put in some local file (after tomcat start) into same contex e.g : `C:\Project1\target\web\yada_yada.jpg` but when access to url `http://localhost:8080/Project1/yada_yada.jpg` seems the added file not found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed to get hints from this post
[mvn tomcat7:run - How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823346/mvn-tomcat7run-how-does-it-work). 
For `mvn tomcat7:run` the `warSourceDirectory` points to *src* by default (not *target*). Now overwrite `warSourceDirectory` will give an exploded version alike.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-beta-1</version>
    <configuration>
        <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/target/web</warSourceDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```